# Integrate with google disabled for individual installs not working consistently

Tags: google-apps-marketplace

I'll describe the flow with screenshots for the sake of simplicity.

We have an an integration page on our application (for G-Suite domains) which includes the "Integrate With Google" button. We allow installation for only domain super admins by leaving the "Enable individual install" checkbox on marketplace API dashboard, unchecked.

[image]

The flow on the application is like that:

1. Go to integration page while logged out and try to click the "Integrate With Google" button.

[image]

now we get the correct error message that user must be logged in, and log in to google from another tab.

[image]

2. Login from different tab to a **Non Super Admin G Suite Account**
3. Try to click the button and get the correct error message

[image]

4. Refresh the page and try again to click the Integrate With Google, the problem here is that now I'm redirected to my application home page, the error message from step 3 is not showing up.

***note*** when I try this flow and login as personal user (gmail.com - not gsuite user) this works as expected even after refreshing the page.

Can you please advise me what to do?

Comment: Can you provide a link to the integration page or send it to atamalet@google.com please?

Comment: Yes of course, first thing tomorrow morning, thanks.

Comment: As discussed with Dima, this is not reproducible.